# Не правильно работает :before в option

Tags: html, css, jquery, firefox

Всем привет.

Делаю список стран через select => option. В option добавил :beforeи к ним уже привязал картинку. но отображает не корректно. В остальных браузерах все ок.

```
<select name="permittedLists" id="permittedLists" multiple>
   <option data-before="true" data-icon="glyphicon-bfh-flag-AF">Afghanistan</option>
   <option data-before="true" data-icon="glyphicon-bfh-flag-AL">Albania</option>
   ...
</select>
```

option задал  position: relative, a
option:before position: absolute.

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить)

[Ссылка на пример](https://test-links7.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: Как временное решение pos-a на pos-r + display: block и переназначить позиции.

Comment: "В остальных браузерах все ок" - поподробнее. Где отображается корректно, а где нет?

Comment: Теги посмотри, написано же мозила

Comment: @TigranVardanyan большое спасибо, работает)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно во-первых задать content: "";, если это нужно

Во-вторых задать ему значение свойства display, например block

И чтобы увидеть его задать ширину, высоту и фон или границу псевдоэлемента

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста более подробный ответ. Приведите пример для наглядности.